# creating image inside a folder results in creating an image with name folder/image.jpg

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, intervention

I have this piece of code:

```
    $file = $faker->image($dir = public_path().'/tmp', $width = 800, $height = 600, '', true);
    $hash = str_random(7);
    $thumbnailName = $hash . '.jpg';
    $thumbnailImage = ImgResizer::make($file)->fit(180, 180);
    $thumbnailImage->save( public_path() . '\\thumb\\'. $thumbnailName);
    rename($file, 'public/'.$hash.'.jpg');
```

As you can see I am using `faker` to populate the database. Faker supports images as well and it's getting images from lorempixel.com. I save this image directly in public folder and that works. I also create a thumbnail of the image using `InternventionImage` and save it to public/thumb folder as you can see in the code.

When I run the db:seed, no errors were produced, it all went well. However when I looked inside thumb folder there were no files there. There were bunch of images created inside public folder but not inside thumb. I logged in the server and cd into default folder and typed ls and I got this output:

[image]

As you can see on the image there are bunch of `public/thumb/hashcode.jpg` images there. How is this possible, they are not inside thumb folder, why is it listing them there? Did the script instead create file with filename `public/thumb/hashcode.jpg`? How do I put them inside thumb folder? This code works on my local machine windows 10 under apache2 and php7.

Comment: The problem is that the follwoing code public_path() . '\\thumb\\'. $thumbnailName creates images in public_path()  with name '\\thumb\\'. $thumbnailName.  Use public_path() . '/thumb/'. $thumbnailName to save them inside thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this:

```
public_path() . '\\thumb\\'. $thumbnailName
```

To this:

```
public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'thumb'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$thumbnailName
```

Also, create `thumb` directory and set correct permissions:

```
chmod -R 755 /public/thumb
```

Comment: I ended using public_path() . '/thumb/'. $thumbnailName as suggsted by Andrej above. However your answer also works so I'll accept it as the answer to question.